# java socket programming for gps device

Tags: java, sockets, gps

We are working on Java Based Socket Programming for GPS Device to get various Attributes of the device like.

1. Device Lat and Long
2. AC ON/OFF
3. Engine On/OFF
4. Relay and Other Attributes.

The issues we are facing is by SMS its giving the device attributes but through programming we are unable to get that.

Device is sending login request to server but unable to get connected.

Listers and port both are open to get the request from device.